# How to Resize Image Files Sizes in React Native

Tags: react-native

My server allows upload of up to 10Mb files.
However, 
I've fixed the image resolution to 1920x1080
but some high resolution images exceed 10 MB.
Can I resize images larger than 10MB to less than 10MB?

I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` to get the image.

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        cropping: true,
        cropperToolbarTitle: 'crop',
        cropperCircleOverlay: true,
      }).then((image) => {
        this.setState({
          imageSource: {
            uri: image.path,
            type: 'image/*',
            name: 'baseImage',
          },
          imageURI: image.path,
        });
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-image-resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer). 
For example :

```js
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';
...
...

ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080,
  cropping: true,
  cropperToolbarTitle: 'crop',
  cropperCircleOverlay: true,
}).then(async (image) => {
  this.setState({
    imageSource: {
      uri: image.path,
      type: 'image/*',
      name: 'baseImage',
    },
    imageURI: image.path,
  });
  await ImageResizer.createResizedImage(image.path, 1920, 1080, "JPEG", 20, 0).then((compressedImage) => {
    // compress image will be low size which will be use to upload to server
  }).catch((err) => {
    this.showError(err);
  });
});
```